# Save a changing variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scope, copy

In my code I want to save an object that changes during the execution in an array inorder to use it after the execution of the function,so I tried to create a copy of it using this approach:

`let copy=[...original]//original is the variable that changes during the execution`  
when I used this approach I noticed that the content of the copied array is the same as the last value of the original array.
Now I need a method that can keep all the states of the original array in one variable.

Comment: do you mean `copy.push(original)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) method which help you in creating a deep clone of a given value using the structured clone algorithm.

```js
// Create an object with a value
const original = { name: "Alpha" };

// Clone it
const clone = structuredClone(original);

// Change original object value in execution
original.name = 'Beta';

console.log(original); // { "name": "Beta" }
console.log(clone); // { "name": "Alpha" }
console.log(clone !== original); // true
```